# click TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'

Tags: python, python-3.x, click, tui

### Hi, I have this problem

> os : linux mint

#### Code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import click

@click.Command()
def main():
    print(f"hello world")
    
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    main()
```

#### Output :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vlad/Desktop/0/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    @click.Command()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

Comment: This means that `click.Command()` expects one argument (a name). So you want something like `@click.Command('my_name')`

Comment: @match I did but the problem was not solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`@click.command()`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/api/#click.command)(with small 'c') instead of [`@click.Command()`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/api/#click.Command). There are two separate objects. `name` for the first one is optional, but the second one is a class which requires `name` parameter. Check their signatures.